# How can I create dummy variables from a factor in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data

```
Yield   Fertilizer
31  1
34  1
34  1
34  1
43  1
35  1
38  1
36  1
36  1
45  1
27  2
27  2
25  2
34  2
21  2
36  2
34  2
30  2
32  2
33  2
36  3
37  3
37  3
34  3
37  3
28  3
33  3
29  3
36  3
42  3
33  4
27  4
35  4
25  4
29  4
20  4
25  4
40  4
35  4
29  4
```

I have to divide fertilizer 1 as dummy variable F1, fertilizer 2 as a dummy variable F2 and fertilizer 3 as a dummy variable F3 and 4 as a base line.

I import this csv file into R by using read.csv function.
But after that when I just use lm function it does not come as I want...
What should I do for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df$Fertilizer <- as.factor(df$Fertilizer)
df$Fertilizer <- relevel(df$Fertilizer, ref = "4")
fit <- lm(Yield ~ Fertilizer, data = df)
summary(fit)
```

Comment: thanks it perfectly shows what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `model.matrix()` function to achieve that.

This should get you started:

```
new_df <- model.matrix(Yield ~ as.factor(Fertilizer)-1,your_df)
```

Comment: can you give me more detail? Ultimately i want to do a regression analysis....

Comment: I edited my answer. Now you should be able to use the new data.frame in a regression analysis.

Comment: I made it as a new data.frame. But when i try to do a regression analysis, the error " corns<-lm(Yield~.,data = cornn)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Yield ~ ., data = cornn, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array" came out...